# Adding and removing Active class on navigation Panels

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp

I tried adding active classes and remove them automatically after visiting another link on the navigation bar.The class active will stay untill i visit another link,but it is not working properly.The cakephp links generate simple anchor tags.Please Help me with this guys..

Here's my Html code

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="border: 1px solid">
  <div class="navbar-header ">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-inverse-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="www.soft.com">company Inc.</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Users', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index')); ?></li>
      <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Department', array('controller'=>'Departments', 'action'=>'index')); ?></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Manage <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <input class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><?php if ($logged_in): ?>

                Welcome <?php echo $current_user['name']; ?>
                <?php endif; ?></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Actions <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Logout', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'logout')); ?></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And Heres my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//active state  
$(function() {
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('li').children('a').removeClass('active');
        $this.parent().addClass('active');

    });
  });
```

});

Comment: After going for new page you want to highlight that page link as active is the that expected behavior?

Comment: Yes that is the required behaviour @GayanCLiyanage

Comment: My best recommendation would be to bind navigation with php function to get url and add active class from server side? or you want client side solution?

Comment: Sorry @GayanCLiyanage I dont no hpw to bind this from server side because i am new to this cakephp and stuff.So Can you please help me with both side bindings..

Comment: Sure I'll add the server side solution as well, Is it ok if I add server side option by tomorrow? Bit sleepy now 4.30 AM :), I added the client side solution below

Comment: Okay pal..U can add it later.I will try this one first.Good Night frnd. @GayanCLiyanage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With page refresh you have to pick the current url to pick the active tab, once you get the path url you can break it down in to segments and by that you can select the active tab. (By accessing action parts of the url you can even set depth active's if you want)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only

    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );//get url segments in to a array

    var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[0];// access url segements(u can even add more depth using this)

    if($('.active').length > 0){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');//remove current active element if there's
    }
    //add class depend on current url's url segment
    if(secondLevelLocation == 'users'){$('li:contains("Users")').addClass('active');}
    if(secondLevelLocation == 'departments'){$('li:contains("Departments")').addClass('active');}
    //add opition by url segments as u want in

    });
```

php version

This is the server side approach. Checking the current controller from the view and adding active class from server if the current controller equals the requested controller.

```
    <li <?php if($this->params['controller'] == "user"){ echo 'class="active"';} ?>><?php echo $this->Html->link('Users', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index')); ?></li>

    <li <?php if($this->params['controller'] == "Departments"){ echo 'class="active"';} ?>><?php echo $this->Html->link('Department', array('controller'=>'Departments', 'action'=>'index')); ?></li>


Please comment if there's something wrong. Below code will help you inspect params available variables. 

      <?php  debug($this->params); ?>
```

Comment: even u can add this form the server side by accessing url and put if on active class by url segment since with each page you send a request to server to fectch the page content, keep me updated if this didn't work out I'll give you that option sample code as well, but if you can add this accordingly this works fine

Comment: ...It's Working nice and perfect..Thanx for your help man.It's  great if you add server side as well.I want to learn about it much betterly...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//active state  
$(function() {
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('ul').find('li.active,a.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        $this.parent().addClass('active');

    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Your code is working without but with preventDefault it's not working,because everytime my the link conent changes after clicking on a link.It is not staying active..can you please add some modifications @OnlyMAJ

Comment: whats the changes of that link ? can you explain me better ?